# Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED only on android

Tags: flutter

I use CachedNetwokImage to display images from meidaserver.

Image display only when i start app on IOS system.

If i start app apk on android i got this error

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```